# Asp.net mvc dropdown code in model or controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I Have created ASP.NET MVC 4 web application which has registration page. it contains two dropdown items.

i want to know where is it feasible to place code for filling up drop down items.as of now its in registation controller but **because of server side validation i wrote same code twice in each method.**

Registration Index

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      var model = new RegisterModel
      {
       TitleList = new SelectList(DataAccess.DAL.DropDownValues("Title"), "Value", "Text"),
       BankList = new SelectList(DataAccess.DAL.DropDownValues("Bank"), "Value", "Text")
      };
     return View("Register", model);
    }
```

Registration Post Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("doRegister")]
    public ActionResult doRegister([Bind(Exclude = "TitleList")] RegisterModel registerModel)
    {
        var model = (RegisterModel)null;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (DataAccess.DAL.registerCustomer(registerModel))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            model = new RegisterModel
            {
             TitleList = new SelectList(DataAccess.DAL.DropDownValues("Title"), "Value", "Text"),
             BankList = new SelectList(DataAccess.DAL.DropDownValues("Bank"), "Value", "Text")
            };
        }
        return View("Register", model);
    }
```

If i didnt initialize model object with dropdown values it throws error in my view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Title, new SelectList(Model.TitleList, "Value", "Text"),
 "Select Title", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**I want to know where i can place my dropdown code ?**

Comment: How about new method that will be called in both actions? Say `CreateRegistrationModel`

Comment: can i write code in model to fill dropdown ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create function right in your controller and call it from both spots. I Don't see anything wrong with that. Besides you are creating instances of SelectList, and I think this falls ok into controller's responsibility.

```
public RegisterModel FillModel()
{
    return new RegisterModel
            {
                TitleList = new SelectList(DataAccess.DAL.DropDownValues("Title"), "Value", "Text"),
                BankList = new SelectList(DataAccess.DAL.DropDownValues("Bank"), "Value", "Text")
            };
}
```

Comment: You might have meant `return new...`

Comment: Is it bad to write same in model ? and then call model method in each controller actions ?

Comment: Your method is supposed to return a `RegisterModel`

Comment: my bad I meant return new.

Comment: @SagarDumbre you can write in the model as well... It just than your model will have using reference just to get to the SelectList class, so I would not do it in the model just because of that.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Title, Model.TitleList,
"Select Title", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Because the definition of Model.TitleList is a `SelectList`

### Edit

You can surround your `DropdownList code` with an `if` clause and check if the model is `null` or no then you will proceed. 
It is better to place your code in the controller than in the View. The view must just present the display of the model in the user interface. And for the controller, it is really the heart of the MVC, the intermediary that ties the Model and the View together, i.e. it takes user input, manipulates the model & causes the view to update

Comment: question is though: I want to know where i can place my dropdown code ?